# Gradle default dependencies when create new project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have some `dependencies` which are used in every newly created project (such as `butterknife`, `support v4`...). Instead of copying the below line every time I create new project, is there any way to configure `Android Studio` to auto add it? :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
```

Comment: Btw, support v7 already includes support v4 transitively

Answer (score 0):

The template for `build.gradle` is in the directory:

```
{sdk-dir}/sdk/tools/templates/projects/NewAndroidApplication/root/build.gradle.ftl
```

You can modify it how you want.

Comment: bigdestroyer: I found the file and modified it w/ my own desired default dependencies. Then I relaunched Android Studio & created a new project.
Your answer did not work for me...the new proj. *.gradle files did not contain my modifications.